# Hard drive making sqeaking noise on spin down

Tags: hard-drive

Just got a WD 2TB WD20EZAZ hard drive that's making an odd squeaking noise on spin down. It sounds as if it's abruptly stopping instead of spinning down slowly. Here's a recording of the noise: https://vocaroo.com/i/s06WDKns00GZ Is this normal or should I return the drive?

Comment: That's not right! Get that returned ASAP before it fails on you.

Comment: @spikey_richie I returned the drive and ordered a new one but it makes the same sound. Did I get unlucky twice? Nothing has been wrong with these drives other than this sound so maybe this sound is normal for this drive?

Comment: strange noises is normal for WD 2 tb 'black' or above